# Masonry Repair - Paver Steps Loose

Tags: stairs, masonry, pavers, walkway

I have some steps on my front walkway that have come loose (marked with blue tape in the pictures).  I've tried fixing these with liquid nails and with epoxy.  But I can't get them to stay.  I've kept the steps dry during the cure period in the instructions and they've been within the recommended temperature range.

What is the right product to use for a fix like this?  These were originally installed about six years ago and I know they used polymeric sand to fill in the gaps (no idea if that matters).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scrape as much of that dried glue off as you can, then use thinset mortar applied with a 1/2" notched trowel.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I've never worked with cement, mortar, concrete at all.  Is something like this what I need to use? https://www.lowes.com/pd/QUIKRETE-60-lb-Gray-Type-N-Mortar-Mix/3006083

Comment: No, use tile mortar, it is called *thin-set mortar*.